# Spring WS SOAP fault response code 500 instead of 400

Tags: spring, soap, spring-ws

Currently I am using Spring WS (spring-ws-core:2.1.0.RELEASE)
I have setup global method security:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

I have an endpoint that throws an AccessDeniedException which I handle with SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver like this:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver"
      class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="defaultFault" value="SERVER"/>
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <value>
            org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException=SENDER, 403 Forbidden
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I get the following response

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
     <env:Fault>
       <env:Code>
        <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
       </env:Code>
     <env:Reason>
        <env:Text xml:lang="en">403 Forbidden</env:Text>
    </env:Reason>
   </env:Fault>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

with an HTTP response code 500.

According to the spec [soap 1.2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part2-20070427/#tabresstatereccodes)

it should return 400.

Is there a mistake on my part or ist just the way Spring WS handles it?

Comment: Did you able to solve this ?

Comment: No I have not. I also asked in Gitter but did not find any answers.